# Цвет заголовка h1

Tags: javascript, css

Всем доброго времени суток!
На сайте есть заголовок h1, который состоит из нескольких слов "Автомобили напрямую из США". Первое слово по видению дизайнера должно быть "окрашено" по-разному. "Авто", "США" - просто обводка букв (text-stroke и прозрачная заливка), "мобили напрямую из" - залито цветом. Например, вариант text.slice(0, 3).style.color - не работает, т.к. должно применяться ко всему элементу, а не к обрезанной части. Подскажите, пож, какие еще есть варианты? Вариант не использовать h1 не подходит, т.к. должно быть семантически верно.

Comment: в чем проблема воткнуть в h1 еще несколько h1 и каждое стилизировать?

Comment: Я смотрела, можно ли вложить в h1 еще что-нибудь типа span, p, h1, но нигде не написано, что так можно

Comment: можно конечно. присваивай каждому класс и стилизуй как хочешь

Comment: На практике-то можно, но ни в одной документации про енто не указано xD Но спасибо!

Comment: очень странно видеть вообще такие вопросы.) удачи